# Sending multiple emails with different attachments C#

Tags: c#, email

quick note before starting, i do know how to send emails with attachments but in this case its just not working. What this code is suppose to do it sends emails with 20 images each. So if theres a folder with 62 images, it will send 4 emails total, last one with 2 images. I found it gets right to the .send bit and crashes. Also the credentials are correct, although i deleted for this post.

```
Decimal EmailCount = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\William\Pictures\Documents\Apple iPhone\").Length) / 20);
        Int32 SentEmails = 0;
        Int32 AttachmentNumber = 1;
        Int32 NewEmail = 1;
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

        do
        {
            MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            MyMailMessage.Attachments.Clear();

            MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("");
            MyMailMessage.To.Add("");
            MyMailMessage.Subject = ("");

            do
            {
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"C:\Users\William\Pictures\Documents\Apple iPhone\" + AttachmentNumber + ".jpg");
                MyMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                AttachmentNumber += 1;
                NewEmail += 1;

            } while (NewEmail <= 20);

            SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            SMTPServer.Port = 587;
            SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
            SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);

            SentEmails += 1;
            NewEmail = 1;

        } while (SentEmails <= EmailCount);
```

Comment: i mean the application goes lighter and my curser just has the loading symbol and if i click it says its not responding. i dont get any exception message

Comment: as @stuartd pointed including any exception info would enable SO to help out with your specific problem rather than simply saying crashed. Also since you making use of Gmail, you better watch out for attachment size limitation (individual file size as well total attachment size). From memory it is 10 MB. I would approach this by initially by attaching single attachment and gradually increase the attachment count for each email. But you would ensure to validate you do not exceed Gmail attachment file size threshold.

Comment: yeh i found 20 images per email is a good size. i found why its crashing. if theres 22 images, its trying to add the 23rd and crashing